# Dynamically created select input using javascript, not showing dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, input, dynamic, html-select

I have created a select input field with dropdown using javascript so user can add multiple entries but the javascript does not pull in the php function used to create the select dropdown values. I am unable to see why the dropdown does not work. The dropdown does work correctly if i create the input field using php.

Javascript

```
<script>
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
 var html = '';
 html += '<label for="category" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Business Category:</label>';
 html += '<div class="col-sm-8">';
 html += '<select name="category" class="form-control">';
 html += '<option value=""></option><?php categoryDropDown($categories); ?>';
 html += '</select>';
 html += '<button type="button" name="remove" class="w3-button w3-red w3-round w3-tiny remove" title="Remove this category"></button>';
 html += '</div>';

 $('#category').append(html) ; 
 count++;
 });

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
$(this).closest('div').remove();
count--;
  });
});</script>
```

PHP Function

```
        $categories = $db->select("categories", "deleted = 0 ORDER BY name");
    function categoryDropDown($categories)
        {
            foreach($categories as $p)
            {
                $output3 .= '<option value="' . $p['id'] . '">' . stripslashes($p['name']) . '</option>';
            }
        return $output3 ;
        }
```

Comment: JS hasn't hit the browser at this point @IncredibleHat. There is still PHP code showing in the markup

Comment: So, you say: "*the javascript does not pull in the php function*" ... and then you say "*The dropdown does work correctly if i create the input field using php.*" ... I'm confused what you are trying to do or expect. 1) JS cannot call a php function directly. 2) Your code is missing an echo to have PHP create the html correctly in the first place. So...... ???

Comment: I have included the following.  <code><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script></code>

Comment: I have tested the dropdown works using a normal php input field so i know the php function is working. I want my user to be able to create unlimited category input fields when they click on a button that says add category. All this is working fine with the javascript except the dropdown does not work. I am trying to echo the the php function but it does not work. If you look at my javascript you will see i am trying to echo the php function with <?php categoryDropDown($categories); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the PHP variable inside a Javascript variable and then append that JS variable like below:

```
<script>
    var count = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
            var options = '<?php echo categoryDropDown($categories); ?>';
            var html = '';
            html += '<label for="category" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Business Category:</label>';
            html += '<div class="col-sm-8">';
            html += '<select name="category" class="form-control">';
            html += '<option value=""></option>';
            html += options;
            html += '</select>';
            html += '<button type="button" name="remove" class="w3-button w3-red w3-round w3-tiny remove" title="Remove this category"></button>';
            html += '</div>';

            $('#category').append(html) ; 
            count++;
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
            $(this).closest('div').remove();
            count--;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but this change cause the javascript to fail where it does not create the new input field at all which it was doing fine before.

Answer (score 0):

Just `echo` the result. You forgot! :-P

```
<?php categoryDropDown($categories); ?>
```

to

```
<?= categoryDropDown($categories); ?>
```

Comment: When i change <?php .....?> to <?= ......?> then my javascript fails and does not even create the new input field which it was doing before but just no dropdown.

Comment: `<?=` is just shorthand for `<?php echo`

Comment: what does the generated html look like?

Comment: Generate HTML creates a new input html-select field when the button is selected to add a new input field but the dropdown does not work. When i make the changes you suggested then the add new input field button does not work at all